# Driving Direction- Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps, android-mapview

I want to draw Driving direction Route from source geopoints to Destination geopoints. I tried  this with the below code but its draw a straight line between the Location not proper shortest route.

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

    Projection projection = classMapView.getProjection();

     Paint   mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);

        GeoPoint gP1 = new GeoPoint(22716221,75896816);
        GeoPoint gP2 = new GeoPoint(22715212, 75895806);

        Point p1 = new Point();
        Point p2 = new Point();

        Path    path = new Path();

        projection.toPixels(gP1, p1);
        projection.toPixels(gP2, p2);

        path.moveTo(p2.x, p2.y);
        path.lineTo(p1.x,p1.y);

        canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
}
```

Please help and also tell me is it possible to get text of direction as Google Maps provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a complete source code at https://github.com/frogermcs/RoutePathExample for how to draw path between two geolocation.

Comment: @Murat Nafiz not anymore valid link.

Answer (score 3):

Please go through [Google Policies](https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup)

This states that turn-by-
turn navigation is not allowed using android MapView.

instead you can use intent to do that as follows

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
 Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=<start lat>,<start lon>&daddr=<dest lat>,<dest lon>"));
 startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve these.

Comment: please check [this](http://blog.synyx.de/2010/06/routing-driving-directions-on-android-%E2%80%93-part-2-draw-the-route/). But before implementing anything like this, do read section 8 of Google Policies. You cannot use directions without prior permission in android mapView.